# Google Analytics - Event Flow report , how to filter only certain events in this report

Tags: google-analytics

In Google analytics, I have more than 10 events being captured via GTM.
In Events Flow report - I only want 5 of the events among the 10 events captured to be shown.

I am trying to show only the Ecommerce events like (Search/ Product Click/ add to Cart/ Checkout).
Other events like scroll depth, submit click, need not be shown.

How to achieve this ?

Edited : Tried with Custom Segment event filtering, however while using this segment it fetches all other Events also.

[image: Custom Segment created]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Custom Segments](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3124493?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) are your friend here. Create a new custom segment that will limit users or sessions to those who have triggered any one of the events you want to include in your report.

In Analytics, click the Segment (it'll typically say, *All Users*) and click the red **+ New Segment** button. You'll need an advanced segment, select either sessions or users depending on which you'd prefer. Then include dimensions relevant to the events you want. You can filter by Event Category, Action, or Label and you can chain several filters through AND/OR options.

Do be aware when using segments that Analytics will tend to default to the last one used, so if you're not familiar with using them get into the habit of double-checking which segment is active when reviewing data and especially when generating reports.

This is the only way to filter the flow reports (both Behaviour Flow and Event Flow) as there are no other filter options for these reports.

Comment: Thank you for your response !

Comment: GeoffAtkins -   As u mentioned, I created a custom segment and in the filter section, filtered it based on ONE particular event using "Event Category" and "Event Action". 
The filter type is either "Session" or "User" , and generated the Events report - I still can see other events coming up in the report. Double checked if only this segment is selected while viewing. 
My understanding is, the filtered "Event Category" will only appear while using this custom segment. Tried in custom reports also, but still brings all other events. I am to do anything else ?

Comment: Updated the post with the created segment screenshot

Comment: @Sannn - It won't filter out those other events, but it will only show them if they are triggered within the filtered set of users or sessions.

Comment: Ok, Thank you again :)

Comment: GeoffAtkins - One more question, will sequence under the Custom Segment help me with Event flow ? If I set more than a couple of events in "Sequence" of custom segment, will it get me the report according to the event flow set up in Sequence order ?

Comment: That does depend on the order in which the events trigger.